# calculate time duration between two modes in a log file by python

Tags: python, time, duration, logfile

Hi I have a log file of a device with ON/OFF mode and I want to calculate the "ON time duration" ON-->OFF time.
Does anybody know how can I do this in python? I am using "re" and "datetime" modules but I am not sure if its the right way or not.
Bellow is some parts of the log file.
thanks

```
Jul 11 16:11:58:710 [139681125603136] dut: Device State: ON
Jul 11 16:11:58:710 [139681125603136] dut: Subscribe request received from 172.17.60.11/49248
Jul 11 16:11:58:962 [139681125603136] dut: sockAccept: new socket fd=31
Jul 11 16:11:58:962 [139681125603136] dut: sockAccept: new session nims=0x17279e0 new=0x1759750 fd=31 10.238.40.228/48002<-10.238.40.228/37400
Jul 11 16:11:58:962 [139681125603136] dut: RREQUEST: verify_login <-10.238.40.228/37400  h=367 d=147
Jul 11 16:11:58:962 [139681125603136] dut:  head  mtype=100 cmd=verify_login seq=0 ts=1499811118 frm=10.238.40.228/37400 tout=180 addr= sid=zYyeCp56Cg4og2P41oP7yQADMTQ5OTgzMjcxMwFheGEtdWltc2VydmVyMS1kZXZf
Jul 11 16:11:58:962 [139681125603136] dut:  data  time=1499811118 cmd=probe_list
```

[Lof File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qhr4o.png)

Comment: Please provide more information about the log file and it's structure

Comment: I just upload it on my post.

Answer (score 0):

You will need datatime and regex.

```
  - regex to extract the date in text line.
  - datetime to represent the date for python
```

Here a simple demo:

```
 - I show you how to use regex to get the date elements
   you can use those to create a datetime
 - Or if you have the full date as a string, the you use strptime to do the conversion
```

I think others show you how to handle the difference of 2 datetime in python. It gives you a timedelta, and you can have the difference in microseconds, seconds, or days.

```py
import re
from datetime import datetime

pattern=re.compile(r"(?P<year>\d\d\d\d)-(?P<month>\d\d)-(?P<day>\d\d) (?P<hour>\d\d):(?P<minute>\d\d):(?P<second>\d\d),(?P<microsecond>\d\d\d)")
logline="2021-10-20 13:12:21,697 - root - DEBUG - begin:test(4), pattern:%d%d(4), next:(0)"

m=re.search(pattern,logline)
if m:
    print(f"Dict with string valiue : {m.groupdict()}")

    extracted_date=dict([(k,int(v)) for k,v in m.groupdict().items()])
    ### ATTENTION ###
    ### extracted_date["microsecond"] are in fact milisecond in the pattern
    extracted_date["microsecond"]*=1000

    print(f"Dict with integer value : {extracted_date}")

    begin_date=datetime(**extracted_date)
    print(str(begin_date))

else:
    print("notfound")

end_date=datetime.strptime("2021-10-20 13:38:12,456000", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S,%f")
print(end_date)

delta=end_date-begin_date

print(f"Delta in seconds   : {delta.seconds}")
print(f"Delta microseconds : {delta.microseconds}")
print(f"Delta days         : {delta.days}")
```

Comment: I just show you add an example of logline , so you have to adapt the pattern in my code

Comment: Thanks for your help. I could not get how can I put ON, OFF mode in the script.

Comment: You will need a pattern like that: 
```pattern=re.compile(r"(?P<month>[A-Z][a-z][a-z]) (?P<day>\d\d) (?P<hour>\d\d):(?P<minute>\d\d):(?P<second>\d\d):(?P<microsecond>\d\d\d).*Device State: ON") ```

Comment: Oh ok,many thanks. And in which line I can open my log file and give a directory?